# optimal algorithm for determining correct object type from ID

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

Let's say I have a database of Objects, Persons and Buildings.

An example of a Person ID is PRS001.

An example of a Building ID is BUL001.

Persons is a table holding all the persons; Buildings is a table holding all the buildings. Object holds all the Persons and all the Buildings.

Now if I extract all data from Object, how do I know if it's a Person or a Building?

I could do something like this:

```
if(start_of_string_is(BUL))
    then it's a building
else if(start_of_string_is(PRS))
    then it's a person
```

But is there not a more succinct and sexier way of achieving this outcome?

Comment: No, that is the sexiest possible algorithm given the circumstances.

Comment: Are buildings and persons the same type of object?

Comment: Is this a composite key?

Comment: @Asad: There's an even sexiest algorithm, by joining the tables.

Comment: The start string always will be comprised of 3 chars?

Comment: @JvdBerg: no. different types of object

Comment: @Mark Baker: no. single field key;

Comment: @MrGoobri: See my answer, you can make use of instanceof

Comment: As your objects are being returned from the database?

Comment: ok, but how they are being returned?

Comment: @FabianoLothor: as an array but that's not important. They can be returned anyway you suggest. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a fundamental design flaw here. A `person` is **not** a `building`, and a `building` is **not** a `person`.

In the object orientent world, those would be different type of objects, and to check a instance of a object against its type you would use [InstanceOf](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php).

Furthermore, you are using the key to get information about the record. That is not how keys suppose to work. Keys uniquely identify a record, without having a meaning.

To make things worse, you already have 2 tables. So why not instantiate a person object from the persons table, and a building object from the buildings table. [PDO can instantiate](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) those objects automatic on fetching.

Example:

```
$person = $statement->fetchObject ( 'person' );
```

when fetching a row from the persons table.

Comment: I agree. A person is not a building but they do have common characteristics such as ID, Title, Description and similar fields. It was decided that all common fields should be inherited from a common table --- i.e. object.

Comment: "Keys uniquely identify a record, without having a meaning." I'm not sure where you learned that, but you should hunt down that teacher and poke him in the eye with a sharp stick. Candidate keys have two characteristics: 1) they're unique, and 2) they're irreducible. Neither of those two characteristics have anything to do with meaning. (Or both do, since examples in textbooks about the relational model are usually based on meaningful data.) I think that data in the periodic table of the elements has 4 candidate keys, all meaningful.

Comment: I was under the assumption that he used primary keys with a meaning. Why the down vote?

Answer (score -1):

Mr Goobri, you informed me that the string will always start with 3 characters, then you can do the following:

```
// Sample:

$ids = array('BUL001', 'PRS001');

foreach($ids as $id) {
    switch (substr($id, 0, 3)) {
    case 'BUL':
        // it's a building
        break;
    case 'PRS':
        // it's a person
        break;
    default:
        // invalid
        break;
    }
}
```